# why i cannot make it go to next row?

Tags: html, css

```css
p {
  font-size: 150%;
}

body {
  background-image: url("images/gg.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.rTable {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 450px;
}

.rTableHeading,
.rTableBody,
.rTableFoot,
.rTableRow {
  clear: both;
}

.rTableHead,
.rTableFoot {
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.rTableHead {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 36%;
}

.rTable:after {
  display: table-cell;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

.rTableHeads {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 55%;
}

.rTableCell {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 17px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 15%;
}

.rTableCells {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 15%;
}

.rTableHea {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 36%;
}

.rTables {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3px 1.8%;
  width: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>hey contact </title>
</head>

<body>
  <p style="text-align: center">
    <a href="index.html">index</a>
    <a href="about.html">about</a>
    <a href="media.html">media</a>
    <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
  </p>
  <div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <form>
        <div class="rTableHeads" align="center"><strong>Contact me</strong></div>

    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableCell"> <label for="Name">Name:</label></div>
      <!--label 
   is to lable name -->
      <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp;
        <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter 
      name" name="name">
      </div>
      <!--placeholder let the enter name comment come out -->
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableCell"><label for="Email">Email_address:</label>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp;
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter 
 email" email="email">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableCell">Subject :
      </div>
      <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp; <select name="subject">
<option value="webt">Web Design</option>
 <option value="programming">programming</option>
<option value="data">Data management</option>
<option value="math">Math</option>
 <option value="MPU">MPU</option>
 </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
      <div class="rTableCells">Message :
      </div>
      <div class="rTableHea">&nbsp;
        <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="30">
    </textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTables" align="center"> </div>
    <!--<div class="rTableHeads" align="center"><strong>Contact me</strong>
  </div> -->
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to make a row after the message row , but when I want to make a row it won't let me make the row. Not sure why. Can anyone help me ??

Here is my result : [image]

Why cannot I create a row, but it moves to beside the message part? Can anyone tell me why I cannot enter another row under the message row ?

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ?

Comment: Indentation matters!  Please fix the indentation in your example. From a quick look I think the problem comes from unclosed or mismatched tags, and fixing the indentation will make it easier to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both;` to the `.rTables` class.

**Option 2:**

You can put **rTables** class inside the **rTableRow** div like so:

```
<div class="rTableRow">
  <div class="rTables" align="center">  </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you want to make a table, please use the html [table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) structure, it will help you a lot.